# How to revert a commit which is not the latest

Tags: git

I'm using Egit. In one of my git project i had to preserve the latest commit but delete the previous commit.

For example,
If HEAD points to latest commit.
Followed by previous commit.

Could anyone please let me know if this can be achieved ?

Answer (score 1):

[git revert](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-revert) would be an option:

```
git revert <commit>
```

It will create a new commit reverting changes.

Another option, preferably if you did not pushed your changes to a remote, is to use [git rebase](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-rebase) in [interactive mode](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Rewriting-History) to put the commit you want to discard latest, then reset that commit